# R String, return a boolean vector of if or not the character is alphabetic

Tags: r, regex

I was wondering if there is a way I can do something like this:

```
str = "3 .*MTNs2 AB33"
```

This is a string of 14 characters

I would like to have R return a vector of length 14, and true if this character is [a-zA-Z], and false if otherwise.

So it should return

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Is there a function that does that?

All the best,

Kathy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grepl("[A-Za-z]",unlist(strsplit(str,"")))
```